# A suggestion for a change by reviewers

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-order

One of the suggestions that I got in my paper review is just indicated as a mistake in

> There is, however, no proven criterion when to stop.

What is wrong with the above sentence. Word ordering? Placement of "however"? I'm currently implementing the changes proposed, but I'm not sure about this one.

Comment: What changes were proposed then?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what it means without context, but *criterion* here probably needs to be followed by *as to*.

Comment: Or maybe just "on" - that's what I was thinking. But I agree with you, something needs to go between _criterion_ and _when to stop_.

Comment: My guess was'for', but the I started wondering if 'criterion' was the right word. Maybe change to 'indicators for'?

Comment: The unclarity is due to the choice of _proven criterion_, which is an awkward phrase. Criteria are set, not proven; and they're set before, not afterwards. All the attention shifts away from the present question of when to stop and back to the many repeated trials in the fruitless attempt to prove ... _What?_ Put a different word there that fits better with the sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is missing the word "for". Also, as a taste matter, that middle inserted "however" looks awkward. I'd prefer to see it reformulated as:

> However, there is no proven criterion for when to stop.

If you just put the "for" (or I suppose "as to" like BE suggested, but I don't like that as well) in there, it would technically be proper English though.